# parse userdata field of all key frames of MPEG header from rtp video stream using GStreamer

Tags: gstreamer, mpeg, user-data

How to parse MPEG stream using GStreamer..? I need to process all userdata field of only key frames(not P-Frames) of MPEG stream.

MPEG stream is coming through rtp protocol. I am able to display the video using GStreamer pipeline, but, my final requirement is to parse userdata field of all key frames and overlay that info into the display video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using fakesink in pipeline and adding handleoff callback function